# Assigning array of values to the corresponding objects dynamically

Tags: java

I have a question. I have 3 classes

```
public class cls1{
    private String A;
    private String B;
}

public class cls2{
    private String C;
    private String D;
}

public class cls3 extends cls1{
    private String E;
    private String F;

    private cls2 cls2;
}
```

I have these 3 classes. cls1, cls2 are the normal classes but cls3 is extending cls1 and it has a component cls2.

I will query and get the results of cls3 from database but the output is in the form of "List". Object[] has all the cls3 parameters values. It includes cls1,cls2 parameters as well.

So here my question is how can I assign the values dynamically to all the classes. I will assign these values and I will use these values in some other place like "cls1.getA(), cls1.getB(), cls2.getC(), cls2.getD()" and so on.

So how can I assign array of values to these corresponding classes. I am thinking it's possible with BeanUtils. Is it possible with BeanUtils...?

Can anyone guide me on this please...

Comment: So you have an array of `Object[]`, it has objects from three classes, and you want to separate them? Is that it?

Comment: I have List<Object[]>. Each Object[] has values belongs to these three classes.

Example:
Forloop(List<Object[]>)
    cls3.setE(Object[0]);
    cls3.setF(Object[1]);
    cls3.getCls2().setC(Object[2]);
    cls3.getCls2().setD(Object[3]);

and so on...

So I need to assign these values with out calling the methods explicitly (Like in the above).

Comment: Why do you want to avoid calling setter ?

Comment: I just want to do it dynamically instead of calling each setter method  separately...

Comment: Use an ORM like JPA or MyBatis. Thats' what they're for.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ORM like hibernate. You need to map your domain model cls1,cl2,cls to your underlying persistence store using JPA. This is a much cleaner approach than rolling your own.

Comment: Hay Thanx for your answer. If possible can you please provide an example program so that I can understand much more clear...